# what is this following error about in spring rest webservice api?

Tags: java, spring, mysql-workbench

I'am creating a restapi , i am using java spring and i'am getting the following error.

**Error:** 
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

My daoImpl class

```
@Override
    public String getLoginDetails(VendorLogin vendorlogin) {

        String getVendorData = "select vendor_ID from vendor_login where vendor_ID= ? 
                                 and password=?";

        String name =null;
        try{
        name = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getVendorData,new Object[]{
       vendorlogin.getVendorLoginId(), vendorlogin.getPassWord()}, String.class);

        }catch(Exception   e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
        return name;    
    }
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.REQ_MAP_LOGIN, 
                method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String vendorloginMethodPost(@RequestBody VendorLogin vendoridlogin)  {
        String message = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
        String id = dao.getLoginDetails(vendoridlogin);
        String password = dao.getLoginDetails(vendoridlogin);

        if (id == null && password==null) {
            message = "login FAIL";

        }else{
            message =" login Successfully";
        }

        return message;
    }
```

Comment: well, your request to the DB expects one, and exactly one result, but there are no results found.

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) explains it quite nicely.

Comment: check return queryForObject is  null

Comment: you have to edit your try catch with  EmptyResultDataAccessException instead of Exception for more details check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
@Override
public String getLoginDetails(VendorLogin vendorlogin) {

    String getVendorData = "select vendor_ID from vendor_login where vendor_ID= ? and password=?";


try {   
    name = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        getVendorData,
        new Object[]{vendorlogin.getVendorLoginId(), vendorlogin.getPassWord()},
         new RowMapper<YourVendorObject>() {
     public UserAttempts mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        // we suppose that your vendor_ID is String in DB
        String vendor_ID = rs.getString("vendor_ID");
        // if you wanna return the whole object use setters and getters
        // from rs.getInt ... rs.getString ...
        return vendor_ID;
     }
    });

   return name;

} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    return null;
}       

}
```

public class EmptyResultDataAccessException extends IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException

Data access exception thrown when a result was expected to have at least one row (or element) but zero rows (or elements) were actually returned.

The problem is, Spring throws an EmptyResultDataAccessException, instead of returning a null when record not found : 
JdbcTemplate .java

```
package org.springframework.jdbc.core;

public class JdbcTemplate extends JdbcAccessor implements JdbcOperations {

     //...
    public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, 
        RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException {
    List<T> results = query(sql, args, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<T>(rowMapper, 1));
    return DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(results);
    }
```

DataAccessUtils.java

```
package org.springframework.dao.support;

public abstract class DataAccessUtils {

    //...
    public static <T> T requiredSingleResult(Collection<T> results) 
         throws IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException {
    int size = (results != null ? results.size() : 0);
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException(1);
    }
    if (results.size() > 1) {
        throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1, size);
    }
    return results.iterator().next();
    }
```

> check it here  : [source](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/queryforobject-throws-emptyresultdataaccessexception-when-record-not-found/)

Comment: When i have changed sql query ,,,,,,,,,,String getVendorData = "select vendor_ID  from vendor_login where vendor_ID='" + vendorlogin.getVendorLoginId() + "' and password= '" + vendorlogin.getPassWord()+ "'"; below error will come
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Edit your answer and past you edited code to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

```java
try {
    String getVendorData = "select vendor_ID from vendor_login where vendor_ID= ? and password=?";

    String name =null;

    name = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getVendorData,new Object[]{vendorlogin.getVendorLoginId(), vendorlogin.getPassWord()}, String.class);

} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    return null;
}
```